# Passing Arguments into Symfony 3 Form configureOptions

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following form:

```
class TestFormType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $testArgument;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (isset($options['testArgument'])) {
            $this->testArgument = $options['testArgument'];
        }

        $builder->add('textField', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $optionsResolver)
    {
        $optionsResolver->setRequired('testArgument');

        $optionsResolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => get_class($this->testArgument)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I am passing the value for the `testArgument` attribute via form options (Symfony 3 modifications), but when is comes to get the class name of the attribute to set the `'data_class'` inside `configureOptions` method, it is always `null`. Basically I need to depend on the form type class attribute inside the `configureOptions` method.Can someone please help me out here to the right direction ?

Comment: According to php doc `get_class` Returns the name of the class of which `object` is an instance. Returns `FALSE` if object is not an object.
If object is omitted when inside a class, the name of that class is returned. maybe `get_class` return false because you do not passed an object to it.

Comment: Pretty sure configureOptions gets called before buildForm.  Might add some die statements to confirm.  More importantly, the form system only creates one object of a particular type.  So if you were planning on have two different instances of this type, each with a different data_class, then it won't work at all.

Comment: @MohammadZareMoghadam: It always returns `'TestFormType'` since `configureOptions` runs before `buildForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to pass the dependency in `configureOptions` method from the form factory `create` method itself:

```
$form = $this->factory->create(
            'app\TestBundle\Form\Type\TestFormType',
            $this->testArgument,
            array(
                'data_class' => get_class($this->testArgument)
            )
        );
```

as it would not be set by the default settings in the form type and had to refactor the form type class as follows:

```
class TestFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('textField', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set this value in the parent form using this one?

Answer (score 1):

**You should pass the *Type __constructor for use  to**

```
use App\Entity\Blog;  
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;  
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BlogType extends AbstractType {

    private $someDependency;

    public function __construct($someDependency)
    {
        $this->someDependency = $someDependency;
    }
    // ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'empty_data' => new Blog($this->someDependency),
        ]);
    } }
```